# Edit MainPage title in Silverlight 5

Tags: xaml, data-binding, titlebar, silverlight-5.0

We're going to use Silverlight 5 for an out-of-browser application and need to have an individual title of the main window. In Silverlight 4 it was not possible to set this property as far as I know (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018081/edit-title-in-silverlight-4) issue). By default the main window has the title of the project followed by "Application". Does Silverlight 5 bring the ability to change the main window title? Maybe even during runtime via data binding?

Comment: It seems to be possible to adjust the main window title in the "OutOfBrowserSettings.xml". But how to change it during runtime via data binding?

Comment: Look at the below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445505/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-the-application-in-out-of-browser-mode-in][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445505/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-the-application-in-out-of-browser-mode-in

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445505/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-the-application-in-out-of-browser-mode-in][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445505/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-the-application-in-out-of-browser-mode-in

Answer (score 0):

In your silverlight project-->Properties->OutOfBrowserSettings.xml you can update the Title.

Please find my sample Settings Page below.

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings ShortName="My OOB Application" EnableGPUAcceleration="False" ShowInstallMenuItem="True">
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>This is my first OOB Application in SL 5.0</OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
    <WindowSettings Title="My OOB Application" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.SecuritySettings>
    <SecuritySettings ElevatedPermissions="Required" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.SecuritySettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons>
    <Icon Size="16,16">Images/XX-16x16px.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="32,32">Images/XX-32x32px.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="48,48">Images/XX-48x48px.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="128,128">Images/XX-128x128px.png</Icon>
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons>
</OutOfBrowserSettings>
```

Here, WindowSettings-->Title will give the Main window title & ShortName will give the Application name in the shortcuts.

Thanks & Regards,
Rousseau Arulsamy

Comment: Thx Rousseau. But this is not new o me, as I already posted in my comment on the first post. The main question is how to change it during runtime via data binding, since we use the MVVM pattern and need a really loose coupling.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the main window application can be adjusted during runtime only via "Application.Current.MainWindow.Title". This doesn't really comply to the MVVM approach since you can't bind to title property of the main window. This is only possible for child windows, since you create those yourself in your code and have full control over them. The main window is provided by the system and is created during application startup. So you can't bind to the properties during runtime. During initialization the main window is set up with the parameters from the "OutOfBrowserSettings.xml" As I said, it is only possible to adjust the main window parameters "directly" via Application.Current.MainWindow...