# Is it Possible To change the Title of the application in Out-of-Browser mode in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a silverlight 4.0 application where I need to change the Window Title of the application after login to the application according to the User in the Out-of-Browser mode.

Is it Possible ?

I have gone through the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68955/Silverlight-4-How-Can-I-Create-a-Customized-OOB-Wi

Thanks
Chittaranjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible in Silverlight 4.

In Silverlight 5, it's very easy, provided you're running with elevated trust:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Title = "Your new window title";
```

However, the [MSDN documentation for the Window.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.title(v=vs.95).aspx) property clearly states that this property is only supported in Silverlight 5.